# Set value on an entire column of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to set the entire column of a dataframe to a specific value.

```
In  [1]: df
Out [1]: 
     issueid   industry
0        001        xxx
1        002        xxx
2        003        xxx
3        004        xxx
4        005        xxx
```

From what I've seen, `loc` is the best practice when replacing values in a dataframe (or isn't it?):

```
In  [2]: df.loc[:,'industry'] = 'yyy'
```

However, I still received this much talked-about warning message:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_index,col_indexer] = value instead
```

If I do

```
In  [3]: df['industry'] = 'yyy'
```

I got the same warning message.

Any ideas?  Working with Python 3.5.2 and pandas 0.18.1.

---

**EDIT Jan 2023**:

Given the volume of visits on this question, it's worth stating that my original question was really more about dataframe copy-versus-slice than "setting value to an entire column".

- On copy-versus-slice: My current understanding is that, in general, if you want to modify a subset of a dataframe after slicing, you should create the subset by `.copy()`. If you only want a view of the slice, no `copy()` needed.
- On setting value to an entire column: simply do `df[col_name] = col_value`

Comment: You must have done something to `df` prior to calling `df.loc[:,'industry']='yyy'` as what you posted should've worked. Basically the warning gets raised if you took a slice or sub-section of your starting df which you didn't show

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Python can do unexpected things when new objects are defined from existing ones. You stated in a comment above that your dataframe is defined along the lines of `df = df_all.loc[df_all['issueid']==specific_id,:]`. In this case, `df` is really just a stand-in for the rows stored in the `df_all` object: a new object is NOT created in memory.

To avoid these issues altogether, I often have to remind myself to use the `copy` module, which explicitly forces objects to be copied in memory so that methods called on the new objects are not applied to the source object. I had the same problem as you, and avoided it using the `deepcopy` function.

In your case, this should get rid of the warning message:

```
from copy import deepcopy
df = deepcopy(df_all.loc[df_all['issueid']==specific_id,:])
df['industry'] = 'yyy'
```

---

**EDIT**: Also see David M.'s excellent comment below!

```
df = df_all.loc[df_all['issueid']==specific_id,:].copy()
df['industry'] = 'yyy'
```

Comment: This can (I think) also be done without the `copy` module by using the Pandas `copy` function (_e.g._ `df=df_all.loc[df_call['issueid']==specific_id,:].copy()`)

Comment: also `df = pd.DataFrame(df)` makes a copy.

Comment: sorry, if it possible, can yo add to your answer explanation of another answer

df.iloc[:]['industry'] = 'yyy'

is it correct?
and why )

Comment: This answer puzzles me. After all the fire dance, and magic pixie dust, at the bottom of the line, the answer ended up with the same thing:
df['industry'] = 'yyy'

So what's the point?

Answer (score 159):

You can use the [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) function:

```
df = df.assign(industry='yyy')
```

Comment: This method worked for me without giving me warnings.

Comment: this should be the answer. a good answer is useful to everybody. not just the one who asked.

Comment: How can I use this approach with a multiindex?

Comment: This didn't throw a warning.

Comment: Just to note, if your column name has spaces like "my industry" then it would be `df = df.assign(**{"my industry": 'yyy'})`

Answer (score 34):

```
df.loc[:,'industry'] = 'yyy'
```

This does the magic. You are to add '.loc' with ':' for all rows. Hope it helps

Comment: This still throws the 'SettingwithaCopy' warning.

Answer (score 14):

You can do :

```
df['industry'] = 'yyy'
```

Comment: Still the same warning message.

Comment: How is constructed your dataframe ? Because I don't have this warning when doing this with a random dataframe.

Comment: df is taken from a broader dataframe df_all.  something like df = df_all.loc[df_all['issueid']==specific_id,:].   I think you've got it, because when I do df_all['industry']='yyy' I don't see this message.  But I don't know why df is not a "normal" dataframe.

Comment: it's your df = df_all.loc[df_all['issueid']==specific_id,:] ; try to use df = df_all[df_all['issueid']==specific_id] instead

Comment: Yes got it.  Care to explain what's the difference between the two?  Does it have something to do "a copy"?

Comment: I don't really know, I've learned with this synthax, sorry :)

Comment: `df['industry']` returns a reference to only a slice of your entire data set (if your data set is large). So you're really only changing a small portion of all the data. This is meant to be used as a fast preview. Use `.loc` instead.

Answer (score 5):

For anyone else coming for this answer and doesn't want to use copy -

```
df['industry'] = df['industry'].apply(lambda x: '')
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your Data frame is like 'Data' you have to consider if your data is a string or an integer. Both are treated differently. So in this case you need be specific about that.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [('001','xxx'), ('002','xxx'), ('003','xxx'), ('004','xxx'), ('005','xxx')]

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['issueid', 'industry'])

print("Old DataFrame")
print(df)

df.loc[:,'industry'] = str('yyy')

print("New DataFrame")
print(df)
```

Now if want to put numbers instead of letters you must create and array

```
list_of_ones = [1,1,1,1,1]
df.loc[:,'industry'] = list_of_ones
print(df)
```

Or if you are using Numpy

```
import numpy as np
n = len(df)
df.loc[:,'industry'] = np.ones(n)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 4):

This provides you with the possibility of adding conditions on the rows and then change all the cells of a specific column corresponding to those rows:

```
df.loc[(df['issueid'] == '001'), 'industry'] = str('yyy')
```

Answer (score 3):

Seems to me that:

`df1 = df[df['col1']==some_value]` will *not* create a new DataFrame, basically, changes in `df1` will be reflected in the parent `df`. This leads to the warning.
Whereas, `df1 = df[df['col1]]==some_value].copy()` *will* create a new DataFrame, and changes in `df1` will not be reflected in `df`. The [`copy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html) method is recommended if you don't want to make changes to your original `df`.

Answer (score 2):

Only use them instead:

```
df.iloc[:]['industry'] = 'yyy'
```

remember: this only works with exist columns in dataframe

*this for people who didn't work .loc*

Comment: Thanks, but can you explaine - why?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue before even with this approach `df.loc[:,'industry'] = 'yyy'`, but once I refreshed the notebook, it ran well.

You may want to try refreshing the cells after you have `df.loc[:,'industry'] = 'yyy'`.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to go under pandas (at numpy level) to do the assignment
using the `.values` attribute

```
df['industry'].values[:] = 'yyy'
```

Answer (score -3):

if you just create new but empty data frame, you cannot directly sign a value to a whole column. This will show as NaN because the system wouldn't know how many rows the data frame will have!You need to either define the size or have some existing columns.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df["A"] = 1
df["B"] = 2
df["C"] = 3
```