# Python: Add Count of Rows from df to Another df as New Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rows, shapes

Let's say I counted the number of rows in a pandas dataframe.  I use the following code to do that:

```
df.shape
```

It gives me the following result: (1700, 12)

How do I add the 1700 value to an existing pandas dataframe? We'll call the column associated with that value D.

Current dataframe:

```
A    B   C
30   40  text
```

Desired dataframe:

```
A    B   C       D
30   40  text    1700
```

Comment: `len(df)` will return 1700.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set value to an entire column of a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44723183/set-value-to-an-entire-column-of-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

you store your shape in a variable of type tuple and then you create a new column and paste the first value of the tuple

```
tab = df.shape

df['D'] = tab[0]
```