# Concatenate pandas Data frame with Series and multiply the second element

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas data frame with many rows and columns like this

```
Name        Skill       Age
Adam        C++         23
Beth        Java        25
Micheal     Scala       21
...
Aaron       Erlang      23
```

I have another list from which i can create a pandas series

```
dept = ['Country', 'UK']
pd.Series[dept]
s = pd.Series(dept)
```

Now i want to concat the dataframe and the Series with Second element of the list should be repeated.

```
Name        Skill       Age         Country
Adam        C++         23          UK
Beth        Java        25          UK
Micheal     Scala       21          UK
...
Aaron       Erlang      23          UK
```

UK should be repeated and the Country should become the label for the series.

I am clueless on how to achieve this

Comment: what about this `df['Country']='UK'` without a series

Comment: @MohamedThasinah exactly. @jhon.smith no need for `series`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set value to an entire column of a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44723183/set-value-to-an-entire-column-of-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Hey Mohamed Thanks that's brilliant i was stupid not to think of an simple and elegant solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select values of list by indexing for column name and for values:

```
dept = ['Country', 'UK']

df[dept[0]] = dept[1]
print (df)
      Name   Skill  Age Country
0     Adam     C++   23      UK
1     Beth    Java   25      UK
2  Micheal   Scala   21      UK
3    Aaron  Erlang   23      UK
```

If input data is `Series` select by position by [`Series.iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iat.html):

```
s = pd.Series(dept)
df[s.iat[0]] = s.iat[1]
#if default RangeIndex
#df[s[0]] = s[1]
```