# How to put a parameter in the assign function of DataFrames?

Tags: python, dataframe, assign

I would like to iterate over the columns and change the content of the columns with the assign function.

[Related to this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44723183/set-value-to-an-entire-column-of-a-pandas-dataframe)

So in that example they show that you can use the assign function:

```
df = df.assign(industry='yyy')
```

To change the content of the column called industry.

I thought I could perform:

```
for column in df.columns[1:]:
     df = df.assign(column='yyy')
```

But now a new column with the label column is created, instead of all columns obtaining 'yyy' as content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following snippet will do what you expect :-)

```
# Option 1

for col in df.columns:
     df.loc[:, col] = 'yyy'

# Option 2 (with .assign())

cols = {col: 'yyy' for col in df.columns}
df = df.assign(**cols)
```

**Input:**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]